# How to dynamically populate NSOutlineView's columns?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nsoutlineview

I have an IBOutlet to an NSOutlineView and I want to remove the existing columns and 
add the new ones.

I have tried this to add columns

```
[outlineView setOutlineTableColumn:myNewCol];
```

and

```
[outlineView addTableColumn:myNewCol];
```

with no luck.

To remove I tried this:

```
NSArray *existingColumns = [outlineView tableColumns];
for (NSTableColumn *col in existingColumns)
    [outlineView removeTableColumn:col];
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`setOutlineTableColumn:` sets the column that has disclosure buttons in it. It doesn't add columns.

If both of those are simply not doing anything, make sure `outlineView` (which, I assume, is an IB outlet) is connected in your nib.

If something else happens, please tell us what in your question.

Comment: Thanks... your answer gives me a clue to figured out what was the problem. I have this line after a [outlineView reloadData] : [outlineView expandItem:nil expandChildren:YES]; .. apparently, this triggered the unwanted behavior... by the other hand, I am not able to remove all columns, it is necessary to have at least one column, which is the [outlineView outlineTableColumn] and it seems to be no solution for this, so I just mutate that one instead of trying to replace it .. Many thanks..